Comparing $\;\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}\;$ and $\;e^{\sin x}-\cos x\;$ as $\;x\to0^+$

As $x\to0^+$, compare two following infinitesimal function:
$$\alpha(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}} \qquad\text{and}\qquad\beta(x)=e^{\sin x}-\cos x$$

The answer is $\beta(x)=o(\alpha(x))$ or $\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=0$ but I can't prove it
I have tried $e^{\sin x}-\cos x=e^{\sin x}-1+1-\cos x$
cause $e^{\sin x}-1 \sim \sin x$
and $1-\cos x\sim\frac{x^2}{2}$
but I can't do anything more.

The ratio should be $\beta(x)/\alpha(x)$

I fixed it, thank you a lot

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left( \frac{e^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}\right)$$

We have that, as suggested in the comments, by standard limits
$$\frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=$$
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}\frac{\sin x}x\frac{e^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x} +\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to 0\cdot 1 \cdot1+0\cdot\frac12=0$$
indeed $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=x^\frac34\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt x+1}}\to 0$, or also
$$\frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\sqrt x+1}}\frac{e^{\sin x-\log (\cos x)}-1}{\sin x-\log (\cos x)}\frac{\sin x-\log (\cos x)}{x}x^\frac34\to 1\cdot1\cdot 1 \cdot 0$$
As an alternative by first order approximation

$\sin x =x+o(x)$
$e^{\sin x}=1+x+o(x)$
$\cos x =1+o(x)$

$$\frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{x+o(x)}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{x^\frac34+o( x^\frac34)}{\sqrt{\sqrt x+1}}\to 0$$

Your idea is fine but I suggest to use little-o (or big-O) notation to handle the remainder, that is

$e^{\sin x}-1 = \sin x+o(x)$
$1-\cos x=\frac{x^2}{2}=o(x)$

then for the denominator it suffices note that

$\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}=\sqrt{\sqrt x(\sqrt x+1)}=\sqrt[4] x\sqrt{\sqrt x +1}$

therefore
$$\frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{x^\frac34}{\sqrt{\sqrt x +1}}\frac{\sin x + o(x)}{x}=\frac{x^\frac34}{\sqrt{\sqrt x +1}}\left(\frac{\sin x}x + o(1)\right)\to 0\cdot 1=0$$

For $x > 0$ is $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}} \ge \sqrt x \ge 0$, and therefore
$$
\left| \frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}} \right|
\le \left| \frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x}} \right|
= \sqrt x \cdot \left| \frac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{x} \right| \, .
$$
The second factor on the right-hand side has a finite limit for $x \to 0^+$, so that the product converges to zero.

Just for giving another way.
$$\dfrac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=\frac xx\cdot \dfrac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}$$
$$\dfrac{e^{\sin x}-\cos x}{x}=\dfrac 1x+\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}+\dfrac{O(x^2)}{x}-\dfrac{\cos(x)}{x}=\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{x}+\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}+\dfrac{O(x^2)}{x}\hspace1cm(1)$$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}{x}=\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}}\hspace1cm(2)$$ We are done because in $(1)$ the limit is $1$ while in $(2)$ the limit  is $\infty$.
